# jQuery - Clone <div> with form elements, including their values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, formset

I have a Django formset, which has lots of form elements. I have a working method to create a new empty form, but I also need a solution to copy a form. Technically, all forms are in a div, like this:

```
<form>
...
    <div class="subform">
         ...
    </div>
...
</form>
```

The problem is, that in latest jQuery versions, html and replaceWith methods don't handle input values, so they create empty form elements instead - which is not the behavior I need. Of course I could implement an algorithm which iterates over all the elements, copies them and sets their values, but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

I want to replace an existing form with the copied values.

Comment: Did you try `clone()` instead of `html()`/`replaceWith()`? It will preserve the `value` properties of your `<input>` elements, and can even preserve event handlers and custom data.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I have, and that perfectly working. That's how I create a new form. (Of course it has lots of django-specific stuff too). But in this case I have to replace an existing form with the new one.

Comment: Well, you could also use it to copy existing forms. `yourForm.clone(true).replaceAll(yourForm)` should work.

Comment: At first sight, it seems to be perfectly working! Thanks! Would you answer for bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes can use [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [replaceAll()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/) instead of `html()`/`replaceWith()`. `clone()` will preserve the `value` properties of your `<input>` elements, and can even preserve event handlers and custom data.

You can write something like:

```
var theForm = $("selector-matching-your-form");
theForm.clone(true).replaceAll(theForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Frédéric has a brilliant answer, and it took me a while to understand it.  Here is a different version:

Make a variable that references an element.

`var someElement = $("input#some-element");`

Clone the element

`var cloneOfElement = $someElement.clone(true);`

Use the clone to replace original element, by using the variable that references the original element.

`cloneOfElement.replaceAll( $someElement );`

--

From the replaceAll() documentation: 
"The .replaceAll() method is similar to .replaceWith(), but with the source and target reversed."